# How Do I Do Analytics on a Website That Has Rasters, Not the Normal DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, raster

I want to be able to use Google Analytics to analyze an educational/mathematical gaming site that uses rasters for graphics.  I am trying to figure out what technology they are using.  I don't know how to see the source code.  It almost looks like Flash, but its not flash.  Can someone give me some guidance as to how I can start doing analytics on a site that uses rasters and not the normal DOM elements.  Does that make sense?
 The website is m.polyup.com

Comment: What is a raster? This question doesn't make sense to me. And that website doesn't even load on my browser. It's just a gray background